# Показ буквенной captcha

Tags: android, kotlin, captcha

Имеется captcha, реализованная через библиотеку 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'. Как можно реализовать отображение данной captcha на разметке активности (на макете)?

UPD:

https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/ библиотека

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    
    <com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Необходимо, чтобы она отображалась в макете, как это можно сделать?
UPD 2:
Как написать код для данной капчи в классе?

Comment: так довольно сложно чем-то помочь. Приложите код того что у вас есть, приложите нормальную ссылку на библиотеку,  и  уточните вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: @Andrew update сделал

Comment: а разметку активности приложите пожалуйста еще, и что значит показывалась? есть какие-то условия или просто чтобы на активности висела капча и все?

Comment: @Andrew висела, выдавала буквенный код, и чтобы его можно было вводить в текстовое поле для валидации (обычная проверка на робота)
разметку к сожалению не могу предоставить

Comment: @Sergey1996, не отображается в приложении, или вы хотите в студии чтобы на вкладке дизайна показывалась картинка? Если последнее то не получится - картинка генерируется только из кода.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev в приложении. То есть по идее - разместил правильно, но ни кода, ни рамки под капчу - ничего нет

Comment: @Sergey1996, читайте внимательно страницы с проектами, там есть даже [пример приложения](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvgsampleapp). PS. проект очень древний, не факт что взлетит без дополнительных действий.